# PropertyInfo.CanRead and PropertyInfo.CanWrite

Tags: c#

I'm a little confused as to how PropertyInfo.CanRead/Write works.

I've got one particular property on a class where CanRead returns true and CanWrite returns false. However, if I try to do property.GetValue(myObject,null) on this property, I get an exception message, "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."

If I'm able to read this property, why would GetValue() fail?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Is there any further information about the exception (f.e. in the inner exception)?

Comment: Good suggestion. I'll take a look at the inner exception and the getter. Something might be happening there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In essence, what you're trying to do is correct.

```
public class Test {
    public string Prop { get; private set; }
    public Test() {
        Prop = "abc";
    }
}

....

Test t = new Test();
var pi = t.GetType().GetProperty("Prop");
if(pi.CanRead) {
    Console.WriteLine(pi.GetValue(t, null));
}
```

But since you're getting an exception, something else is going wrong. Could it be that your instance, `myObject` is actually null? Other than that, it's quite possible that something entirely different is going on inside the property getter, that is causing the exception

Answer (score 4):

`CanRead` only indicates that the property has a get accessor. It doesn't say that you are allowed to call it, it could still be private. Use `BindingFlags` to call private properties.

Comment: Which BindingFlags shold be used?

Answer (score 0):

The exception text hints that the exception is thrown by the getter. Did you examine the Inner exception? Did you try to put a breakpoint on the first line of the getter?

Comment: Good suggestion, I will do so.